# bzip2 a tar folder

Tags: tar, gzip, bzip2

I just create a tar directory of 600G test.tar inside dir1 .

my question the only space available I have now 300G in dir1

I m looking for some ways to generate the compressed test.tar.bzip on the

dir1 meaning it won't create a new file I will have only test.tar.bzip

Comment: Can we assume that you have tried to compress the file and failed since it did not compress down to 300 GB?

Comment: yes, because I can't have the test.tar and test.tar.bzip in the same directory dir1 because space available only 300G and test.tar have 600G

Comment: Do you still have the original directory? If so why not write a compressed `tar` file? See the `j` or `z` flags for GNU `tar`, or pipe the tarfile through a compressor before writing to disk.

Comment: The suggestion @roaima gives is correct - compress while tar-ing - `tar cjvf archive.tar.bz2 /path/to/directory/to/archive`

Answer (score 4):

Let's suppose you created the tarball of `/some/big/directory` named `test.tar` with a command like the following

```
tar cf /path/to/test.tar /some/big/directory
```

Space permitting you can now compress the tarball with a command similar to one of these:

```
bzip2 /path/to/test.tar    # Produces test.tar.bz2
gzip  /path/to/test.tar    # Produces test.tar.gz
```

Alternatively, you can tell `tar` to create one of these files directly by using the `j` or `z` flags, like this:

```
tar cjf /path/to/test.tar.bz2 /some/big/directory
tar czf /path/to/test.tar.gz /some/big/directory
```

If you don't have a `tar` with these flags you can pipe the output instead:

```
tar cf - /some/big/directory | bzip2 >/path/to/test.tar.bz2
tar cf - /some/big/directory | gzip >/path/to/test.tar.gz
```

Comment: Hi Roaima , Thanks for you answer , I understand good what you write but my question with your example :   I create test.tar in directory1  that have 600G so space left only 300G . so if I create bzip2 /path/to/test.tar  I will have both test.tar and test.tar.bz2 in the same folder  my question it's how I can use bzip2 and have only one compress test.tar.bz2

Comment: @Jcob if you have the original directories then just remove your 600GB tarball and generate a compressed one. If you don't, then you will need to find another chunk of disk to perform the compression because you can't compress an existing tarball incrementally.